# Should I completely eliminate try/catch from code where I use (Bluebird) promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, livescript

I have a couple very basic setup steps before I call my promisified functions and I am considering wrapping them in a try/catch block because that seems the simplest way. However, it seems a little dirty to me.

Should I instead make a function that returns a Promise, even if it is very simple? Here is an example.

```
try
  thingyId = req.params.id # here I am 99.999% sure that params is defined,
  # but if for some bizarre reason it's not, I'd like to handle that error
  # instead of breaking the whole program
catch
  console.log "error: " + e

# do normal promisified functions
```

or should I write this as

```
setThingyId = (req) ->
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) !->
    if req.hasOwnProperty "params"
      resolve req.params.id
    else
      reject new Error "no params"

setThingyId(req)
  .then (deviceId) ->
    # other promisified functions
```

Comment: If it does not depend on asynchronous behaviour, `try`/`catch` does exactly what you're looking for. If it does, wrap it in a promise.

Comment: You can handle `req.params.id` being undefined without having to wrap it in a try/catch. Just check for it, if it's there continue if not do something else

Comment: Thank you. It does not depend on asynchronous behavior. I would use if...else but there are other synchronous functions that also throw errors and they can all be handled the same way so it would be nice to keep it a little dry-er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - that's actually a good question.

- If a function is synchronous - do NOT return a promise and do NOT utilize bluebird in it. It is slower than synchronous execution and harder to debug. Using try/catch for synchronous code is very appropriate. You could instead of course perform the `"params" in req` in an `if` instead of using exceptions at all which is likely more appropriate.
- If a function completes its task in an asynchronous manner and returns a promise, you can use `Promise.method` to make it throw safe.

So in your case I'd do:

```
setThingyId = (req) ->
    if req && req.params && req.params.id
       someCalculationOverReqId req.params.id
    else 
       handleExceptionalCase req
```

Here's Promise.method:

```
setThingyId = Promise.method (req) ->
    someCalculationOverReqId req.params.id
```

Note that this only makes sense if the function returns a promise, what this will do is turn any throws to rejections effectively making the function throw safe.

Comment: Awesome thank you. It is synchronous, and there are other synchronous functions in the setup so I think I'll just have them throw exceptions in edge cases as well and I can catch them all the same way.

Comment: @Californian right, that's what you should do. Synchronous functions should not use promises altogether.